# Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I am getting this error while locally running it. but it is building properly.

When i remove 
 
from index.html it works fine but now build does not work.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: It works with out this (npm start)   <script src="/dist/bundle.js" async></script>
But can not build(npm run build) without this script .  I have not use hooks in my code

Comment: Is your component where you are using hooks a 'function component' ?

Comment: No. sometimes this error changed to Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error #321 for same code.